# BTRFS defragment only new files added after last defragmentation

Tags: btrfs, defrag

I am using `sudo btrfs fi defragment -rv /media/user/mountdir` to defragment my offsite server backups now counting millions of small files an several TB of data. Every time I run the defragment command, it starts over and flies through all the already defragmented files.

How can I start where I left off?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but isn't that command just translated to a kernel ioctl call?  Is there anything that tracks "last defrag time" for files/dirs?  What happens if you use the command multiple times, but each time further down in the directory structure?

Comment: Have you considered mounting with the `autodefrag` option?